# Is there a possibility to have left and right drawer on one page at the same time using react-navigation 3.*

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native "0.59.1" and react-navigation "3.4.1". The problem is that I need to have left and right drawers on the single page. Both left and right drawers must be able to toggled by "swiping"(native behavior) or navigation bar buttons.
So I'm wonder if this is possible at all in react-navigation "3.*"? And if yes - what is the approach?

I tried to implement it like:

```
createDrawerNavigator({ // drawer_0
  Root: createDrawerNavigator({ // drawer_1
    MyScreen: MyScreenContainer
  }, { drawerPosition: 'right' })
}, { drawerPosition: 'left' })
```

But in result I'm able to open only 'drawer_1'(the "right" one) from the 'MyScreenContainer' page using:

```
 - "swipe"
 - this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
```

Comment: you could have a single root drawer ... and it's content could be changed dynamically when rendered on left or right